# Space in the content of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Today I faced a weir bug in UITableView.
I have a UIViewController containing a UITableView. I also have a root viewcontroller, which will add the aforementioned UIViewController as a child.
Now when loaded, it shows a space between cells and the top border.
How can I fix that?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deselect `Adjust Scroll view insets` option of the `ComicsVC` view controller.

First select `ComicsVC` item in the left window of your storyboard, then in the attributes inspector you will easily find this checkbox.

[image: Adjust Scroll view insets option]

Comment: Thanks, I had to deselect "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in root vc but your idea helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set top position of UITableView to `0`. Also you have to add constraints between UITableView and parent UIView.

This bug appears when you use translucent navigation bar.

Comment: I already added the constraints (leading, trailing, top and bottom)

Comment: @lenhhoxung did you set top constraint value to `0`?

Answer (score 0):

That space shows up for grouped `UITableViews`, and is usually occupied by a section header. If you don't implement a section header, then the area will be blank.

If you don't have more than one section, go to the `UITableView` in the storyboard, show the properties, and change the style to `Plain`.

Hope this helps!